# urllib2.urlopen timeout works only when connected to Internet

Tags: python, python-2.7, timeout, urllib2, raspbian

I'm working on Python 2.7 code to read a value from HTML page by using urllib2 library. **I want to timeout** the urllib2.urlopen function after 5 seconds in case of no Internet and jump to remaining code.

**It works** as expected when computer is connected to working internet connection. And for testing if I set `timeout=0.1` it timed out suddenly without opening url, as expected. **But when there is no Internet, timeout not works** either I set timeout to 0.1, 5, or any other value. It simply does not timed out.

This is my Code:

```
import urllib2
url = "https://alfahd.witorbit.net/fingerprint.php?n"
try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url , timeout=5).read()
    print response 
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

Result when connected to Internet with timeout value 5:

```
180
```

Result when connected to Internet with timeout value 0.1 :

```
<urlopen error timed out>
```

Seems timeout is working.

Result when **NOT** connected to Internet and with any timeout value (it timed out after about 40 seconds every time I open url despite of any value I set for `timeout=`:

```
<urlopen error [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution>
```

How can I timeout *urllib2.urlopen* when there is no Internet connectivity? Am I missing some thing? Please guide me to solve this issue. Thanks!

Comment: A failure in name resolution takes place before the request, so my guess is that name resolution not the subject of the timeout. You can avoid this by manually resolving the name to its IP in your `/etc/hosts` file. Then your timeout should behave as expected.

Comment: I opened 'sudo nano /etc/hosts' now how can I add name to IP in etc/hosts for example for my given url? what should I write in this file?

Comment: You write a new line in the file that starts with the IP address of the host. Then a tab (or other whitespace) then the hostname(s) you want to resolve to that IP. e.g. `10.10.10.10    alfahd.witorbit.net` (replacing the `10.10....` with the actual IP). See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592618/hosts-file-change-syntax) from ask ubuntu.

Comment: Yes this solution worked for me. Thanks a lot..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because name resolution happens before the request is made, it's not subject to the timeout. You can prevent this error in name resolution by providing the IP for the host in your `/etc/hosts` file. For example, if the host is `subdomain.example.com` and the IP is `10.10.10.10` you would add the following line in the `/etc/hosts` file

```
10.10.10.10    subdomain.example.com
```

Alternatively, you may be able to simply use the IP address directly, however, some webservers require you use the hostname, in which case you'll need to modify the `hosts` file to use the name offline.